# electron-builder updater is trying to run weird processes that are caught by security policies

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-updater

I am packaging a NodeJS application for Windows (NSIS) and using electron-builder. i also use electron-updater to process updates for this application.

The application need to run into a protected environment.

Lately i issue an update and the updater failed to update because security policies has blocked weird processes that updater tried to launch :

`old-unistaller.exe (well this one seems to be legit) Un_Z.exe Un_Y.exe Un_X.exe`
etc. etc. manay alaphabets like this, and this looks really weird.

The question is why is doing this ? I need and official documentation to explain this behavior so i can forward it to the security team, but i couldnt find any.

Any help would be great !

Tried to search documentation regarding :
`Un_Z.exe Un_Y.exe Un_X.exe etc. etc.`
Couldnt find anything